# Barcode lookups for games, books, CDs

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, barcode

I am looking to write my own media library and was wondering are there any free .Net APIs out there to identify a product based on a given barcode? As a secondary point are there .Net APIs to return cover art for books, CD, games etc based on a barcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use [amazon web services](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) for this.  You'll need to have an account and API key (free) and [download the toolkit for Visual Studio](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/).

To answer your specific question, a barcode scan returns a UPC.  You can use the `ItemLookup` command for the Amazon web service for this lookup, setting the `IdType` to "UPC" and the `ItemId` to the appropriate UPC (barcode scan).

For more info, navigate to the "API reference" in [Amazon's developer guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/).

Here is a very basic C# code sample:

```
        com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookup itemLookup = new com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookup();
        itemLookup.AWSAccessKeyId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

        com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookupRequest request = new com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookupRequest();
        request.IdType = com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookupRequestIdType.UPC;
        request.ItemId = new String[] { "00028000133177" };
        request.ResponseGroup = new String[] { "Small", "AlternateVersions" };
        itemLookup.Request = new com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookupRequest[] { request };

        try
        {
            com.amazon.webservices.ItemLookupResponse itemLookupResponse = com.amazon.webservices.AWSECommerceService.ItemLookup(itemLookup);
            com.amazon.webservices.Item item = itemLookupResponse.Items[0].Item[0];
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.ItemAttributes.Title);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Of note, I've written a program to do exactly this.  I've found that Amazon does not always have a match for every UPC (which is expected), but a majority of my items are found in Amazon.  Once you do find a match, you may want to store the ASIN / UPC relationship somewhere, so that you can reference the item by the ASIN (Amazon ID) going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.ozgrid.com/barcodes/barcode-reader.htm

EDIT1: 
An API for the www.upcdatabase.com Barcode Query: http://www.upcdatabase.com/xmlrpc.asp
I cannot provide much information about this, but this might help you. This page has C# VB APIs for querying with a Barcode.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. I have a method of reading the barcode but was looking for a lookup service. For instance if I read a barcode from a CD I would like the artist, album name ans tracklisting returned and if possible the cover images,=.

Comment: updated the answer with EdIT1. Look at the upcdatabase.com link and the provided API. This might help you.

Comment: Thanks Phoxis thats a good start. I am going to start looking at Amazon Web Services to see what that gives.

Answer (score 0):

Hooked In Motion has one: http://www.hookedinmotion.com/?page_id=246